# How do I install Java DB on Windows 10?

Tags: installation, java

I'm trying to work out how to install JavaDB (I have Windows 10).

I've installed JDK 13 and, according to this page, JavaDB should be installed automatically as part of the JDK:
https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/getstart/cgsinstallingderby.html

But I can't find it.  There is no `db` folder in `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13` and no `Sun` folder in `Program Files` either.

In Netbeans, if I go to Services and right-click on Java DB, all the options are greyed out apart from Properties.  If I go to Properties it asks for the JavaDB installation folder.

I tried reinstalling the JDK (just reinstalling, not re-downloading) but JavaDB still isn't there.

Can anyone tell me how I install it / where I should find it once installed, or what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Can anyone tell me how I install it.

> I've installed JDK 13 and, according to this page, Java DB should be installed automatically as part of the jdk

Not any more. Read on.

> Derby was included in JDK from Java 6 under the name JavaDB. However from Java 9, Derby is no longer distributed with JDK, hence we use the brand name Apache Derby instead of JavaDB.
>
> **Download and Install Derby**
>
> To use Derby, you must download the distribution and extract the
> package. The home page of Apache Derby project is
> https://db.apache.org/derby/index.html. Click the Download menu to
> choose a version. At the time of this writing, the current version of
> Derby is 10.14.1.10 which is for Java 8 or higher.
>
> You can see there are 4 different distributions, and choose the bin distribution that contains the documentation, Javadoc, and JAR files for Derby.

Source [How to Get Started with Apache Derby (JavaDB)](https://www.codejava.net/java-se/jdbc/how-to-get-started-with-apache-derby-javadb)

Comment: Just to add to this, there is no need to "install" it.  Just download it, then copy the folder, e.g. "db-derby-10.15.1.3-bin" from the zipped folder to another location, e.g. C:\Program Files\Java.  Also create a folder where you would like to store the databases when you create them. From Netbeans, go to Services, expand Databases, right-click on Java DB, Properties, then enter the location and name of each of these folders.

Comment: @HilaryN You still have to extract the files from the download archive and then (optionally) move them. That counts as installing.